# C++ - Tamanho de um ponteiro de array

Tags: c++, array, ponteiro

Tenho um array:

```
char *exemplo[] = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};
```

E uma função:

```
void myFunc(**myArray)
{

}
```

Então, quero uma função que retorne o tamanho deste array que eu passei como parametro. Por exemplo se eu passasse o array `exemplo` a função deveria retornar `3`.

Eu sei como fazer isso fora da função, mas quando eu passo como parâmetro não da certo.

Comment: "Eu sei como fazer isso fora da função" só por curiosidade, como isso é feito? Eu achava que era impossível... Mas nunca trabalhei a fundo com C/C++, então posso (devo) estar enganado.

Comment: sizeof(exemplo) / sizeof(*exemplo)

Comment: Só por curiosidade, a função `main(int argc, char **argv)` lembra o seu problema.

Comment: Me expliquem como essa pergunta feita por mim agora está como autor @dromenox ?

Comment: @vcatafesta o campo de comentários não devem servir para isso, se tem algum questionamento sobre problemas no site você pode formular uma postagem com detalhes no [META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/). Agradecemos a compreensão.

Comment: @vcatafesta analisando o timeline da postagem não há nenhuma evidência nesse sentido. Se tem algo que corrobore o fato, pode passar diretamente para a empresa analisar, pelo [link de contato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dada uma array:

```
int array[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
```

E uma função:

```
int funcao(int* argumento) {}
```

No momento que você for chamar a função ocorre um **decaimento de array para ponteiro**.

```
funcao(array);
```

E a partir desse momento não é possível saber o tamanho da array de forma alguma. Tudo que resta é um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento. Usualmente se passa o tamanho da array como um argumento adicional. Repare que o seguinte também não funciona:

```
int funcao(int argumento[]) {}
int funcao(int argumento[50]) {} // Você poder por qualquer número ali. É ignorado.
```

Isso é só uma outra sintaxe para exatamente a mesma coisa. Você está pegando um ponteiro como argumento.

No entanto existe uma forma de resolver isso. Em vez de passar o argumento como valor, você pode usar uma **referência para um array**. Assim:

```
int funcao(int (&argumento)[5]);
```

Agora o tamanho da array é mandatório e ele faz sim diferença. Não ocorre o decaimento aqui e você chama da mesma forma que antes: `funcao(array)`. Se você chamar com um array de tamanho diferente de `5` haverá um erro de compilação.

É agora que entra a mágica dos templates. Se só existe um tamanho aceitável para o argumento, vamos fazer o compilador deduzir esse valor por nós:

```
template <typename T, int S>
int size(T (&arg)[S]) { return S; }
```

Dada uma array de `S` elementos do tipo `T`, a função vai retornar o valor de `S`.

Exemplo:

```
int array1[] = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
char* array2[] = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};

cout << size(array1) << endl; // 5
cout << size(array2) << endl; // 3
```

Você pode agora fazer alguma computação dentro da função, já que você tem o tamanho. Mas se lembre que pegou a array por referencia. Então qualquer coisa que mude nela vai afetar a variável passada como argumento.

Comment: nossa ! valeu mesmo ! eu pensei em passar como parâmetro também, mas achava melhor já aproveitar o array que eu passei para pegar o tamanho

Comment: Referências a array são um negócio interessante que o C++ adicionou ao C, mas me pergunto se fazendo assim com templates, não teríamos o caso do compilador gerar no código gerado uma cópia da função para cada tamanho diferente que usarmos... (pois é normalmente assim que templates funcionam). Nesse caso o modo "manual", passando separadamente o array/ponteiro e seu tamanho acaba sendo mais vantajoso.

Comment: @marcus Provavelmente isso aconteceria mesmo, mas por outro lado o número de arrays cujo tamanho é conhecido em tempo de compilação é finito, pra todo o resto essa técnica não se aplicaria (que eu saiba; repito que minha experiência com C/C++ está bem datada). E de qualquer forma, o compilador provavelmente tornaria essas funções *inline* mesmo...

Comment: @marcus Se você passar o argumento do tamanho *hardcoded* na chamada da função, o compilador vai executar a otimização de propagação de constantes e criar cópias da função para cada argumento de qualquer forma (isso em `-O3`). O problema de fazer assim é que você pode passar o argumento errado. Uma solução é fazer a função template em que a única coisa que tem no corpo é a chamada de uma função auxiliar passando o `S` como argumento. Pode usar ainda atributos para impedir o inline se quiser. Mas fazer isso é quase que uma micro-otimização. Em geral deixe para o compilador esse trabalho.

Answer (score 0):

De qualquer forma se torna inútil passar a matriz por referência e ainda passar o número de elementos dela no qual simplesmente poderia passar o número de elementos por outro parâmetro.

O ideal seria que a própria função calculasse o número de elementos da matriz, mas isso se torna impossível pois o `C` passa somente o ponteiro dela e o cálculo com `sizeof()` ou mesmo com *templates* não teria o resultado esperado.

Estou trabalhando em um código assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int LenArray(char *a[])
{
   int nlen = 0;
   //while(*(a+nlen)){
   while( a[nlen] ){
     nlen++;
   }
   return nlen;
}

void main(void)
{
   char *menu[] = {"Incluir", "Remover", "Listar", "Imprimir", 0};
   printf("Tamanho do Array: %d\n", LenArray(menu));
}
```

Resultado:

```
Tamanho do Array: 4
```

Comment: Esse código está errado! Para funcionar, a variável `menu` deveria ter sido declarada assim: `char *menu[] = { "Incluir", "Remover", "Listar", 0 };`. E seria mais inteligível se tivesse usado `a[x]` ao invés de `*(a+x)`. Melhor ainda se em lugar `x` tivesse usado `i`.